# Post-synthetic Anisotropic Wet-Chemical Etching of Colloidal Sodalite ZIF Crystals

Tags: organic-chemistry, crystal-structure

It's well known that Metal-organic Frameworks can be made by attaching inorganic metal ions to organic linkers via strong chemical bonds, ZIF-67 is one of this big family which could be prepared by using Cobalt source with some kind of organic linkers. 
my question is how could we control the structure of ZIF-67 by using wet chemical etching in order to break the links and in particular get sheet like structure?